# iOS App Crashes from Memory Issue when Generating Images from PHAssets

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, phasset

I'm trying to get some photos (`PHAsset`'s) from a user's Photos library, and convert them to `UIImage`'s.

Here's the code for fetching the assets from the library:

```
     func fetchPhotos() {
        
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(mediaSubtype & %d) != 0", PHAssetMediaSubtype.photoScreenshot.rawValue)
        
        //Fetching Screen Shots
        fetchedResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)
        
        let f: FetchResult = FetchResult(fetchedResult!)
        var fetchCount = 0
        
        for i in f {
            fetchCount += 1
            print("Fetch count \(fetchCount)")
            let img = i.getAssetThumbnail()
            testImages.append(img)
        }
    }
```

Below is the code for getting a `UIImage` out of a `PHAsset`:

```
extension PHAsset {
    func getAssetThumbnail() -> UIImage {
        let manager = PHImageManager.default()
        let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
        var thumbnail = UIImage()
        option.isSynchronous = true
        manager.requestImage(for: self,
                             targetSize: CGSize(width: self.pixelWidth, height: self.pixelHeight),
                             contentMode: .aspectFit,
                             options: option,
                             resultHandler: {(result, info) -> Void in
                                thumbnail = result!
                             })
            return thumbnail
    }
}
```

I'm currently getting this crash output when trying to run the code:

```
Details

The app “AppClassificationDemo” on Nick’s iPhone quit unexpectedly.
Domain: IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain
Code: 11
Failure Reason: Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-11-14 22:19:19 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = DBGLLDBLauncher;
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone14,2";
    "device_osBuild" = "16.1.1 (20B101)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 2;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 6369;
    "operation_errorCode" = 11;
    "operation_errorDomain" = IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = DBGLLDBLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 5;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_type" = 2;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos16.1";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "16.1";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 13.0.1 (Build 22A400)
Xcode 14.1 (21534.1) (Build 14B47b)
Timestamp: 2022-11-14T14:19:19-08:00
```

I'm fairly certain it's do the size of the image thumbnail being generated; when I set `width` and `height` to both be 100, the processing works as expected.

When changing it `self.pixelWidth` and `self.pixelHeight`, the app crashes.

Comment: How many images are you processing and what is the value of `pixelWidth` and `pixelHeight`? Unless you are only processing a few thumbnails of reasonable size there are likely better ways to only generate thumbnails as you need them and not keep them all in memory at once.

Comment: I'm processing however many screenshots are on a user's phone. pixel width and height are whatever the corresponding values are of the fetched asset

Comment: OK, so you are not even getting thumbnails but the full-sized images. That's even worse. You really need to rethink trying to load an array of full-sized screenshot images into memory at once. Consider a user will hundreds of screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to convert the `PHAsset` to `UIImage` and store in array. Because `UIImage` will use the full memory size of the image. So too many images in an array will cause a memory leak.

Hence just fetch the required `PHAsset` on demand and request for the `UIImage` when needed. Please see an example below.

```
func loadImageAt(_ index:Int) -> UIImage?{
            
    let asset = fetchResult.object(at: index)
    
    let manager = PHImageManager.default()
    let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
    
    var thumbnail:UIImage?
    
    option.isSynchronous = true
    manager.requestImage(for: asset,
                         targetSize: CGSize(width: asset.pixelWidth, height: asset.pixelHeight),
                         contentMode: .aspectFit,
                         options: option,
                         resultHandler: {(result, info) -> Void in
        
        thumbnail = result
    })
    
    return thumbnail
}
```

Also I will suggest you to use the asynchronous image request to avoid the UI performance issues.

Hope this helps!